# Multiple fonts families throughout the document

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I know this question has already been answered here 
[How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document/37251#37251)

I understand that in order to use additional font with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX one can choose to proceed with:

```
\newfontfamily\myfont{font name}
```

then defining a command

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textmyfont}{\myfont}
```

then using the command

```
Text in the default font. \textmyfont{Text in the new font.} Again text in the default font.
```

But what if I want to have multiple fonts throughout my document? How do I specify the use of a specific font I load with one `\textmyfont` command? How will it know which font to choose out of many I loaded? 
Say, I loaded three fonts:

```
\newfontfamily\myfont{font1}
\newfontfamily\myfont{font2}
\newfontfamily\myfont{font3}
```

how would I modify `\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textmyfont}{\myfont}` command to recognize each font separately? `\myfont2` and `\myfont3` is not working! And then how would I use the actual `\textmyfont` command to reference a specific font to a specific part of the text?

Comment: if you want three font families you should give them different names, but don't use numbers, they are not allowed in command names, use letters, eg. `\newfontfamily\myfontA{font1}`, `\newfontfamily\myfontB{font2}`.

Comment: Then I define `\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textmyfont}{\myfontA}` command to recognize `myfontA` but the command `\textmyfont` stays the same. If I put it before some text, the command will choose `myfont` instead of `myfontA`. So how would I modify the actual command? Or I can rename `\textmyfont` command to anything I want like `\textmyfontA`?

Comment: yes, you can also define \textmyfontA.